# Is there anything regular Torx bits can do that Security Torx bits cannot?

Tags: screwdriver

Is there anything a regular Torx bit can do that a Security Torx bit cannot?

I am puzzled that many compact tool kits which appear to be designed with a lot of thought include both Torx and Security Torx bits when it seems like the latter can do anything the former can do.  The only difference I can tell between the two is that the Security Torx bits have a hole in the center to accommodate a pin in the center of a Torx Security screw.

Comment: Think the strength of security bits would be slightly less if you wrench them, because of the hole.  Without having two to compare right now, maybe the size or number of points might be different(question today asking for seven point instead of six point).

Comment: @crip659 - put that in the answer box down below... The 7-pointers are just one more oddity to sell people more types of bits - normal security torx are 6 point

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I am just guessing.  Have used torx but mainly I just use the bit that fits instead of taking a look at them.  Without the earlier question I could not even tell how many points they had.

Comment: FYI:  You can buy Security Torx drivers on wish.com cheaply.

Comment: I think the whole idea of "security" screws was hatched in the days before Amazon.  To buy a security bit you had to go to a special store, to know what you wanted, to present your face to the store clerk and to pay a LOT of money for a very obscure product.   Today, you can buy literally any security bit for five cents with next day delivery.    The whole concept of "security by obscurity" in the form of hard-to-get screw heads has become ridiculous.   I think your question is backwards .. it's not "why not just make them all security" ... it's "why do security heads still exist?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular Torx (solid) are far stronger, so will undo/do up tighter than the hollow Security Torx. Security Torx are made basically to discourage dismantling of electrical items, which by definition don't need to be torqued up particularly tightly, whereas normal Torx are designed to be torqued up well, and the appropriate tool for the job always does it better!

Comment: I recently snapped a security Torx undoing my bike brake rotor bolts, so it really does happen.  I couldn't find a non-security one.  Luckily the broken tip came out with a magnet

Answer (score 3):

They can prevent you from undoing security torx fasteners.

If you don't need that "feature" you can use security bits instead.

Regular Torx bits might be slightly stronger than security bits, but I don't think that the filled centre adds much strength.

The whole security fasteners racket is mostly a way to keep consumers out of appliances that are not user serviceable, if you have the skill and wisdom not mess with what you shouldn't, you will not be harmed by having security bits.

Cheap tool kits are often padded with junk to inflate the parts count

Comment: Application of a punch with a hammer can convert security Torx screws to regular Torx ;-)

Comment: "Cheap tool kits are often padded with junk to inflate the parts count". So much this! "Oooh... this kit has _100_ bits in it, that must be _better_!" never mind that you'll only ever use 5 of those 100...

Comment: @FreeMan Really depends on how much you do DiY tbh... Occasionally there'll be a new challenge where I'm quite happy that little box that came with my Bosch Ixo contains exactly the right bit, even though in regular use it's like 99% the exact same pozidriv :)

Comment: I got a kit of 100 bits, @MiG. The only one I've used so far is the Y-shaped one that works well to drive cup hooks. Frankly, that alone was worth the cost of the whole set. I've got long Torx & Phillips bits, and haven't done any appliance repair to need any of the other security bits that come with it yet. I've only had it a year or so, maybe in the next 5 years, I'll use one of the other bits... :)

Comment: The security bits will definitely break quicker than the normal ones. You need to not be too rough with them even if you are using them for security screws.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, Don't use a punch to make them. If you do that, you'll likely break the bit. Instead, use a drill press. The best and easiest thing to do is to just go buy a bit if you need it.

Comment: @Ben You use the punch to break off the pin in the screw-head. Then it's a regular Torx. That was useful back when it was actually moderately hard to get your hands on a security Torx bit. Note I said screws, not bits.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, sorry, my mistake.